# Perl localtime error

Tags: perl, time, mktime, localtime

I get the epoch time at February 28<sup>th</sup> 2009, 
 then add to it the number of seconds in a week.
But then I get March 4<sup>th</sup> instead of March 7<sup>th</sup>. Why?

The following is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use POSIX;

my $hours_per_day    =   24;
my $hours_per_week   =  168;
my $seconds_per_hour = 3600;
my $seconds_per_week = ($hours_per_week * $seconds_per_hour);

#begin at my first week
$epoch_seconds = POSIX::mktime(0,0,12,28,2,109);

for(my $cline = 1; $cline <= 250; $cline++) {
    ($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$month,
     $year,$wday,$yday,$isdst) = localtime($epoch_seconds);

    $year += 1900;
    print STDOUT "$cline <=> $year/$month/$mday\n";

    $epoch_seconds += $seconds_per_week;
}
```

Comment: How can you have a gold badge, but not know how to use the markup code formatting?

Comment: @TLP, that's what I want to know. >.<

Comment: four spacebars = "this is code". I guess i do now.

Comment: @HermannIngjaldsson You can also click the code format button, or press CTRL-K.

Comment: @TLP It’s just the `Fanatic` gold badge, proving tenacity not expertise. If you leave a browser window open to StackOverflow with a daily refresh, you get it after 100 days no matter what.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are starting with Mar. 28, 2009 and a week later is Apr. 4, 2009.

```
use POSIX;

my $hours_per_day=24;
my $hours_per_week=168;
my $seconds_per_hour=3600;
my $seconds_per_week=($hours_per_week*$seconds_per_hour);

#begin at my first week
my $epoch_seconds=POSIX::mktime(0,0,12,28,2,109);

for(my $cline=1; $cline<=250; $cline++) {
    my ($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$month,
     $year,$wday,$yday,$isdst) =localtime($epoch_seconds);

    print strftime( "%A, %B %e, %Y\t", localtime($epoch_seconds) );
    $year+=1900;
    print STDOUT "$cline <=> $year/$month/$mday\n";

    $epoch_seconds+=$seconds_per_week;
}
```

PS: You really should use `strftime` to format your dates. See `perldoc POSIX` and search for /strftime/.

Comment: oh darn.. 2 is march.. off course! I just automatically assumed 2 is february.

Answer (score 2):

Not every week is exactly $seconds_per_week long (Leap years etc), you should use a function/library/module that does the calculations for you.

Like explained [here](http://www.perlhowto.com/working_with_date_time) or [here](http://www.perl.com/pub/2003/03/13/datetime.html). Good luck!

Comment: I tried, got into trouble installing the module. Cpan is not the best user interface i have witnessed in my days.

Comment: Hermann Ingjaldsson, vague comment is vague. CPAN is the life-blood of Perl, so we'd rather assist you in installing the most appropriate software. [Open a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) to describe the trouble. - Write exactly which aspect of the user interface you found bad, without critique there's no improvement.

Comment: @HermannIngjaldsson `cpan DateTime` -- not so complicated. Do note that you'll need correct privileges to execute, so depending on your system, you may need to `sudo/su`. With that said, I always prefer to use `apt-get` myself. `sudo apt-get install libdatetime-perl`.

Comment: The solution I have come up with is a CPAN free solution, and hence a better one. I'll post a question when the time is ripe, thanks for the help.

Comment: Having 2 represent februar would be a better user interface actually, one that fits better with the way humans think.

Comment: You would only be right if POSIX's datetime routines and the DateTime distro had the same quality. This is not the case. DateTime is vastly better (months start counting from 1 by default, so you would not trip up with the mistake you made with POSIX because of the stupid C time structure) and actually correctly models time (has timezones, microseconds and leap seconds).

Comment: Ok, so next time the need arises i'll figure out this cpan.

Comment: How does a leap year change the number of seconds in a week?